# module "library" has no attribute "KAKA"

Tags: python

it doesn't do the function. it writes an error.

main.py:

```py
import library

library.KAKA(10, 20)
```

library.py:

```py
class KAKA():
    def __init__(self, fruits, vegetables):
        self.fruits = fruits
        self.vegetables = vegetables
    def get_results(self):
        print(self.vegetables)
        print(self.fruits)
```

i tried this, but it didn't work

Comment: What's your folder structure?

Comment: Run `python -v ...` and see if the right file is imported.

Comment: when i use
```python
from library import KAKA

KAKA(10, 20)

```
it writes: ImportError: cannot import name 'KAKA' from 'library' (unknown location)

Comment: The library should be in the same directory with your main file, otherwise you will have to use different practices.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Edit: This is not a working solution, though OP accepted it as one. In my past this often fixed my issues due to how I structured my projects.

You should do:

```
from library import KAKA
```

and then:

```
KAKA(10, 20)
```

This is called an "explicit import".

Comment: This is not a solution, it is just another style of import.

Comment: How is it not a solution if it fixes the problem? I am well aware that this is just another import style. If you want you can also give the whole path of the library, but this works just fine.

Comment: If you read the comments above you will notice that the OP seems to have marked your answer as his chosen solution, but it doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: I thought because he accepted it, it worked for him. Then he needs to give us the structure of the files and import it like: `from his_path.library import KAKA` or `import his_path.library`